# Getting Twitter friends list

Tags: twitter

I need get a list of friends on Twitter.

I have done Authorization, received tokens.

In official https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/friends/list documents only the basic parameters of the request. How to paste the token? I don't know

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54807221/get-twitter-friends-list-in-swift/54838712#54838712

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to generate the following parameters oauth_signature

- oauth_consumer_key
- oauth_token
- oauth_nonce
- oauth_timestamp
- oauth_signature_method
- oauth_version
- All the parameters of your query

Next, prepare the header body

```
<body> = "oauth_nonce=" + oauth_nonce + "," +

"oauth_signature_method=" + oauth_signature_method + "," +

"oauth_token=" + urlencode(oauth_token) + "," +

"oauth_timestamp=" + oauth_timestamp + "," +

"oauth_consumer_key=" + oauth_consumer_key + "," +

"oauth_signature=" + urlencode(oauth_signature) + "," +

"oauth_version=" + oauth_version
```

Add the header

```
"Authorization: <body>"
```

And send a request